# How to install xampp/lamp server with php v5.5 up in openSUSE 12.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, opensuse

Good day, I am new to openSUSE and we have a local server using openSUSE 12.2 with php version 5.3 and the only available upgrade in the repository is 5.4 only.

I need to install xampp/lamp server with php v5.5 up so that I can meet the minimum requirements for "Laravel framework" because we want to install our laravel app to our local server. Hope someone can help me so that I can accomplish my task..

I'm just a newbie and I dont have experience in openSUSE.

Comment: My guess would be you need to upgrade your repositories or OS, looks like a php 5.6 package is available: https://software.opensuse.org/package/php56 (careful with Xampp, it's not a secure setup).

Comment: and what OS would it be? and how to upgrade a repository? Sir please teach me how to upgrade a repo thats the only option. because our server has another app running.

Comment: I've never used openSUSE, but Linux distros in general use package managers with lists of available packages, which sometimes need updating. Some packages are also not available for older OS versions, so updating the OS may be needed to get access to the newer packages.

Comment: so the only option sir is to upgrade the OS? What Linux OS sir with stable package?

Comment: A newer version of openSUSE maybe? Assuming your current version is outdated. I would expect the OS to have a built-in upgrade functionality.

Comment: Ok sir. thank you. I will just tell my superior that the only option we have is to a upgrade the OS to a newer version.. thank you for your help sir..

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Good day. My office mate manage to install php7 by only downloading a php7 file and then extracted it. but the problem is when I try to type php --version in terminal the result is php7 but when I try phpInfo(); the result is the older version php 5.3 how to set this sir to php 7? and please teach me sir in how to switch or set to another version of php..

Comment: See: [Why is the PHP version different in phpinfo() and CLI?](https://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli)